# powering a device with AC or DC

Tags: power-supply, power

I recently used a small audio device that could be powered by an AC or DC power supply 12-24V. How is this possible? And why isn't it more common? 
Are there reasons that more manufacturers don't follow this route?

Comment: Reasons not to? Money. Not being liable if the user connects an unsuitable supply, rather than the factory approved supply. Money. Money. Some power wastage in the two diode drops when using a DC supply. Failure to sell more replacement units when the user hooks up the wrong polarity DC or an AC supply. Which comes back to money. Of course there is the positive reputation from surviving things that would kill other devices, but that does not show up in hard, cold, cash as easily, so places with shortsighted management concentrate on the money.

Comment: @Ecnerwal--I was thinking a supply with AC/DC input and no polarity might be more dummy proof, but maybe that's just not the case.

Comment: It certainly is more dummy-proof (resistant, actually - the dummys will find a way around any attempt to proof against them.) But then you can't sell the dummy two devices after they fry the first one. Or they'll buy "some other company's product" that costs a dollar less, but which lacks the extra components that make it robust. I personally think that this is a great idea for any power input, but I'm not a cost-cutting vice-president with an MBA - I'm an engineer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fs5Hra.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. AC/DC device powered by AC source.*

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fu1q5H.png)</sup>

> How is this possible?

- The **polarity** question is easy: If the device shown in Figure 1 is powered from a DC supply two of the diodes are permanently reverse biased and are effectively removed from the circuit as shown in Figure 2. If the DC supply polarity is reversed the other two diodes will be used.
- The **voltage regulation** may be a bit more complicated. Linear voltage regulators are cheaper than switched mode voltage regulators but suffer the disadvantage that they burn off the excess voltage as heat. If, for example, our device required 1 A at 12 V and we fed it with 24 V then we would have to burn off 12 V x 1 A = 12 W. This presents a cooling problem. The solution is to use a switched mode power supply which is efficient but more complex or use the linear regulator but specify an AC or DC input sufficient to run the regulator without excessive heat dissipation.

> And why isn't it more common? Are there reasons that more manufacturers don't follow this route?

As explained above, it's certainly more idiot proof but does increase complexity and hence the cost.

Comment: I would argue that a voltage regulator is most likely part of the internal circuit, given the range of input voltage mentioned in the question.

Comment: Argue away. I even copied down portions of the question to make sure I answered the actual question. In doing this I forgot about the opening statement. Answer updated, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Many things are possible  -- but not free.  It's even possible to power off of wall transformers that use both tip positive and tip negative barrel connectors.  Doing such stuff, similarly to allowing both AC and DC power, means that you need more signal conditioning on the power input.  This means more parts on the BOM, and more things to potentially go wrong.

Comment: @ Scott Sideman--and how might one go about conditioning the signal?

Comment: @inbinder For example, a simple diode bridge full wave rectifier.  It doesn't stop working just because the input is DC, but there will be a diode drop.  So, a rectifier, filter, and then a regulator would do just fine, specced correctly.

Comment: @ Scott Seidman--thank you. That was exactly what I was looking for.